# How to check if select query returned values or empty with PHP and SQLite 3

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm using `SQLite3` and `PHP` to create a little class, this means I don't want any plugins or other classes, just plain `SQLite3` and `PHP`.

Currently I'm trying to retrieve values from a database, but I want to check if there is a result or not with that conditions:

`$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM views WHERE address = '$ip' AND page = ''");`

After some search I couln't find nothing specific, but I think I'm missing it.

First I tried:

```
   if($select){
        // result returned
   }else{
        // no results
   }
```

And then this solution worked(the previous always failed):

```
while($row = $select->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
    $exists = TRUE;
    break;
}

if($exists == TRUE){
    // result returned
}else{
    // no results
}
```

But this seems to be, tricky... is there a way to check if a select query returned something or nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one gave the perfect answer, but every comment helped me to get it right. So, if you have the same problem, check all the comments and then my answer. Special help from @Deep

```
if($select->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
    // results returned
}else{
    // no results. empty.
}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can chek it simple in "runtime":

```
$emptyArr  = array();
$filledArr = array(1,2,3,4,5);

if ($emptyArr) {
    echo 'Empty array is not empty!';
}
if (!$filledArr) {
    echo 'Filled array is empty!';
}
```

Because this: http://php.net/manual/ru/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php
Will return **filled array** or **false**. Then this is equal:

```
$arr = array();
var_dump((false == $arr)); // true
```

And special for all dizzzlikers! Incredible, sweet, honey solution:

```
if ($res = $select->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    foreach ($res as $item) {
        // output
    }
} else {
    // nothing
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't using the `!$filledArray` give a PHP Warning if error reporting is on? You can only do that with booleans.

Comment: @Jake And you try it for arrays? )))

Comment: Arrays are handled like variables, so it'd be handled the same way. Both ways you showed are wrong as they're checking if they're true or false which is not something you should do with a variable unless it's set as a boolean.

Comment: I tried that already, that would work if $select was a normal array. But in this case is a SQLite3 Object and not array, basically, doesn't work that way. But thanks for your reply

Comment: @rafaelmsantos When you use fetch style - you known return type

Comment: @Deep, not getting it. Can you be more explicit, please?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you take the variables and could use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
if(!empty($var)){
   // Variable is not empty and is set
}

if(isset($var)){
    // Variable is set, may be empty though.
}

if(empty($var)){
    // Variable is not set or is empty.
}

if(!isset($var)){
    // Variable is not set.
}
```

This would also work for arrays and array keys.

Comment: Fail: $var = 0; var_dump(empty($var)); // true

Comment: @Deep Empty checks if it is empty and set. 0 would correlate with false, which is why it says it is empty.

Comment: $select returns and SQLite3 Object( ), and this doesn't work as arrays.

Comment: More fail: $var = null; var_dump(isset($var)); // false

Comment: @Deep It isn't set? Null != set... are you kidding me?

Comment: @Jake Yes it is set: $var = null; var_dump($var); // NULL nothing notices. But without defined: var_dump($var); // Notice: Undefined variable. It isn't correct behaviour. You must forced only: if (isset($var) && $var !== null) { then variable is defined and set.

Comment: Implementation of isset something like this: (is_defined($var) && $var !== null)

Answer (score 0):

Theres a function called *->numRows();

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-num-rows.php

that returns the number of rows fetched from a database. I don't use sqlite but I'm pretty sure a dbquery returns an array of values from the database (well, in this case an object) along with a true/false if it was successful or not.

Try:

```
$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM views WHERE address = '$ip' AND page = ''");



$rows = $select->numRows();

echo $rows;  //returns # of rows

or    

if ($rows){
//return anything but 0 would eval true..
}
```